# Downloading same files but with different names with Python libraries

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python programming and would like some help fixing my code. I am currently using Python requests library to download a bunch of PDF files from a list of URLs and save them with preset names(this is also extracted into another list). Below is my code:

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path

url = dict_url.values() #list of URLs that I want to download
filename = dict_url.keys() #list of file names that I want to save my downloaded files as

for k in url:
    for i in filename:
        name = Path(i)
        link = k
        response = requests.get(link)
        name.write_bytes(response.content)
```

I got it to work but my outputs are one same PDF file but downloaded many times saved under different names. I would like it to download different PDF files and have it saved with its corresponding name from the list.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! The code has a loop that is basically `for k in foo: download k len(filename) times and save it to different paths`. Can you clarify what the contents are of these dicts and what your links are? Perhaps you meant to run the loops in parallel rather than nested? E.g., `for i, k in dict_url.items(): ...`

Comment: Try something like `for key, value in dict_url.items():`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both your suggestions worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a better result. Having only one loop will allow you to loop through the filename and urls at the same time.

```py
import requests
from pathlib import Path

for i, k in dict_url.items():
        name = Path(i)
        link = k
        response = requests.get(link)
        name.write_bytes(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your nested loops are downloading a single file `x` times where `x` is the number of filenames. It then renames it to each filename. Then you download the next file, rename it `x` times, overwriting the previous download. This can be fixed by removing the nested loop.

```
for k in dict_url: #loop through origional dict
    name = Path(k) #k is key
    link = dict_url[k] #get value by lookup using key
    response = requests.get(link)
    name.write_bytes(response.content)
```